# How to separate data that don't form a sine function from those that do?

Tags: python, filter, trigonometry

I am trying to write a python code that helps me to determine where my real (recorded data in shape of sine function) data start. I have an array with values that are not equal to zero prior to data acquisition and I need to filter these.

I attached an image for better understanding of a problem. I need to define where exactly the first cycle starts.

[plot of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20CJJ.jpg)

A small (critical) part of my data looks like this:
[0.001
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
0.000
0.000
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
0.000
0.000
0.001
0.000
0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
0.000
0.000
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.000
-0.000
-0.000
-0.000
0.000
0.000
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
-0.000
-0.002
-0.002
-0.002
-0.053
-0.053
-0.155
-0.234
-0.234
-0.255
-0.307
-0.431
-0.431
-0.488
-0.566
-0.566
-0.641
-0.785
-0.785
-0.856
-0.932
-1.003
-1.003
-1.149
-1.220
-1.220
-1.298
-1.372
-1.372
-1.523
-1.577
-1.652
-1.652
-1.716
-1.836
-1.836
-1.894
-1.935
-1.935
-1.997
-2.084
-2.134
-2.134
-2.181
-2.216
-2.216
-2.274
-2.298
-2.298
-2.307
-2.318
-2.321
-2.321
-2.318
-2.313
-2.313
-2.300
-2.263
-2.263
-2.240
-2.205
-2.172
-2.172
-2.084
-2.036
-2.036
-1.983]

Comment: Do not really know what you want, do you want the value that has a minimal 0.05difference with the earlier number or what?

Comment: I need to filter the values that are just fluctuating aroung 0 from thos that are constantly increasing/decreasing (creating a sine function). I don't think that setting the difference of 0.05 will be correct, since in the real data can happen that the two consequent values are the same and their difference is 0.

Comment: You can simply use filter function with, res=list(filter(lambda x:abs(x)<0.01,lsts)), while lsts is the list you provided.